# Why has my water filter made my water less clean?

Tags: water, kitchens, water-purification

A few years ago I installed a [Whirlpool under sink water filtration system](http://www.lowes.com/pd_55113-59019-WHKF-DUF_0__?Ntt=whkf-duf&UserSearch=whkf-duf&productId=1188335&rpp=32) that I purchased from [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com), as part of a kitchen renovation.

[image]

I've just replaced the carbon filter again (following the manufacturers procedure (filter [model# WHKF-GAC](http://www.lowes.com/pd_55170-59019-WHKF-GAC_0)), and once again have noticed that the water coming out looks less drinkable than the water coming from any other tap in the house.  The water coming out after not using the faucet for a bit is white (not a bit cloudy, WHITE), and only slightly clears up after running the tap for a minute.

I've followed the manufacturers instructions, and flushed the system for 5 minutes after the filter replacement (what a waste of water).  But the problem persists, and from previous experience will likely persist for the next week or so.  Is there a way to clear up the water sooner, or do I have to continually waste water flushing the system for a minute or so before drinking?

This has been a problem since the first filter was installed, but the water typically clears up after using the filter for a couple weeks.

> ## Filter Cartridge Replacement Instructions:
>
> **NOTE:** Before changing cartridge, turn off incoming watersupply. Place a bucket under filter to catch the small amountof water that will run out after housing removal.
>
> 1. Shut off water.
> 2. Relieve pressure in housing by pushing red vent button.
> 3. Unscrew housing and remove old cartridge. Wash housing thoroughly with mild soap and water.
> 4. Insert new cartridge and re-install housing. Be sure cartridge isseated in the housing before tightening onto head.
> 5. Use filter wrench to fully seat the cartridge. Tighten to make awater tight seal.
> 6. Turn on water. If any leaks appear, tighten housing as needed.
> 7. Flush system for five (5) minutes

Comment: If you fill a glass with water and let it sit, does it stay white or does it clear up?

Comment: @Steven It clears up (settles to the bottom).

Comment: When I replace filter cartridges on my GE dual filter unit it takes about 20 minutes of flushing to clear things out. Save the water for some other use if the volume used bothers you. We take water and use it to replenish in an outdoor fountain.

Comment: Have you tested the water without the filter. In other words, are you sure the water quality is the same as the other faucets in your house WITHOUT the filter?

Comment: @Droid Yes I have.

Comment: I have a similar water filter but dont have the same issue. Apparently neither do any of the other reviewers on lowes website. Since you've replaced the filter, it may be an issue with either the adapter at the cold water line (to enable water flow to filter), the lines to/from the filter, or the filter head/water dispenser itself. Try replacing each of those one by one. It is unlikely the filters themselves are causing the problem. Even when I first "flushed" my filter, the water was never white (maybe a little "oily" at first).

Comment: @Droid If I run the system without a filter at all, the water comes out with no discoloration. It's only when a new filter is installed, so replacing other bits of the system doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Tester101 I see. Sounds like its time to contact the manufacturer then. Either that or switch purification systems. Good luck!

Comment: Due to aeration and fresh surface area, the new filter could be changing the pH of the water, causing minerals in the supply water to precipitate.  Or maybe the filter is designed to adjust the pH. Is it city water or well water? water softener?

Comment: If you install a new filter, then run the water a bit to flush the air out, then (without further use) let it sit over night, then run the water a bit to flush the filter ... well after all that, do you still get a precipitate?

Comment: @mike Yes, the precipitate is still there after a few days of flushing.

Comment: What type of filter element are you using? Is it a white cottony fabric type? Carbon? activated alumina?
Did you flush system without the filter first? Did you clean the filter housing and rinse off the filter before you install it?Is the filter sealing well? Is there a place in the filter housing where unfiltered water may be bypassing the filter?

Are there rubber o-rings that look worn or like they might need to be replaced?

Comment: Did you have this problem for the life (years of ownership) of the filter, since the first filter, or only the last few filters?

Have you tried another model of filter that is compatible with your housing?

You said you tested the water. What did the sediment consist of?

Comment: @hortstu I've updated the question.  The only tests I've done, is to verify the taste, color, and clarity of the water opposed to other faucets in my house.  The water is clean and clear from the tap that is unfiltered, and fed from the same plumbing.

Comment: OK well you might want to get the water tested and see what needs to be filtered out.  Are you saying that the unfiltered water in your home is cleaner than the filtered water?

Comment: @Tester101 Since this has been going on from the start I'd think there might be a problem with the housing or some seal allowing unfiltered water to get past but it sounds like you're saying the filter water is dirtier.  That should just be carbon from the filter. Try cleaning the filter before you use it. Maybe even scrub it a little and see if that helps.  This doesn't explain why your carbon filters are dirtier than everyone elses.

Comment: @hortstu I've tried washing the filters, and it hasn't helped. I'm fairly sure the particulate in the water is not carbon, since it's white not black.  I was guessing it was something left over from the manufacturing process (plastic?), as it does seem to clear up after a bit of use.

Comment: @tester101 That is odd.  I'd get a lab test of your water with and without the filter.  See if whatever that particulate matter is related to the filter or not.  We use carbon filters here and I've never noticed anything like that.  I'll pay closer attention next time.  I always assumed the flushing was to get out loose carbon particles.

Comment: Odd indeed... that filter is just activated carbon and shouldn't release any white particulate. I'd understand if the water came out "white" due to dissolved air being released, but then you wouldn't see any precipitate after the water clears. But perhaps @mike could be right about the filter changing the pH of the water. When you boil water to make coffee or to cook, do you get lime depositing on the pots?

Answer (score 3):

No filter removes all contaminants.  Carbon is great for improving the taste. The white ones remove large sediment. Activated alumina removes some fluoride among other things. Distilled water will be free of most things but volatile chemicals will make it through. UV light and micropores (ceramic and "nano tubes") will remove most virus bacteria protozoa and cysts. Uv light will kill most if not all of those little nasties if the flow is right.

So the first step would be to go get your unfiltered water tested. Then see what's in it that concerns you then figure out what you need to remove those contaminants. Your filter might not be designed to remove the stuff you have a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

I sell and replace these filters all the time. For the first few seconds, black carbon fines are usually flushed out - which is just dust sitting on the outside of the carbon interior core. It is not harmful to drink either. You drink activated carbon (usually compressed into tablets) when you have diarrhea to absorb bacteria causing the diarrhea. If you collect the first few glasses of water, the carbon fines will settle on the bottom after a while.

The 'white stuff' that comes out is nothing else than very tiny air bubbles. Pour it into a glass and you will see them slowly (because they are very small) rising to the top and disappear. This can happen for a few minutes, hours or even days depending on how much you use the tap. It is just air bubbles - so just ignore it. By running the tap for 3-5 minutes, it usually clears it.

Comment: It's not just air bubbles, as the white "*junk*" settles to the bottom of the glass not the top.